# Implementation and performance difference between Python's insert() method and inserting by slicing

Tags: python, performance, list, insert, slice

What is the difference between inserting an element in a python list in the following ways?

```
myList.insert(at, myValue)
myList[at:at] = [myValue]
```

I have run some tests and the performance of the two are very similar, but the slicing insert consistently produces slightly better results. My question is regarding the difference in implementation and performance, not the behaviour.

Comment: My guess is they probably are the same, myList.insert just performs myList[at:at] = [myValue]

Comment: Nope, it shuffles the elements up. I can't find the implementation of the other one. https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/listobject.c

Comment: You can consider the Github référence, now: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c

Comment: In the C source code it's shifting the elements up iteratively. I doubt this is the case for slicing
`for (i = n; --i >= where; )
        items[i+1] = items[i];`

Answer (score 1):

We have the same behaviour, see bellow:

The default behaviour is to insert the item at the given index;
each value at greater index are shifted one position to the end.

```
>>> my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
>>> my_list.insert(5, 'item')
>>> my_list
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'item', 'f', 'g']

>>> my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
>>> my_list.insert(-3, 'item')
>>> my_list
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'item', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

If the list is empty, the item is appended normally.

```
>>> my_list = []
>>> my_list.insert(5, 'item')
>>> my_list
['item']

>>> my_list = []
>>> my_list.insert(-3, 'item')
>>> my_list
['item']
```

If the index is out of bounds, the item is appended to the end if the index is positive or to the beginning if negative.
No exception is raised.

```
>>> my_list = ['a', 'b']
>>> my_list.insert(5, 'item')
>>> my_list
['a', 'b', 'item']

>>> my_list = ['a', 'b']
>>> my_list.insert(-3, 'item')
>>> my_list
['item', 'a', 'b']
```

We have exactly the same behaviour with slice notation,
in the case of a range of same indexes:

```
>>> my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
>>> my_list[5:5] = ['item']
>>> my_list
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'item', 'f', 'g']

>>> my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
>>> my_list[-3:-3] = ['item']
>>> my_list
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'item', 'e', 'f', 'g']

>>> my_list = []
>>> my_list[5:5] = ['item']
>>> my_list
['item']

>>> my_list = []
>>> my_list[-3:-3] = ['item']
>>> my_list
['item']

>>> my_list = ['a', 'b']
>>> my_list[5:5] = ['item']
>>> my_list
['a', 'b', 'item']

>>> my_list = ['a', 'b']
>>> my_list[-3:-3] = ['item']
>>> my_list
['item', 'a', 'b']
```

The slice notation is the same as calling `__setitem__()` method with a `slice` object:

```
>>> my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
>>> my_list.__setitem__(slice(5, 5), ['item'])
>>> my_list
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'item', 'f', 'g']
```

Comment: In my tests, the slicing insert has a slightly better performance consistently. I might not have been clear in my question. It's the implementation I'm interested in, not the behaviour. I'll +1 anyway because it wasn't clear.

Comment: `my_list[5:7] = ['item']` why remove 6. element, I don't get that part

Comment: @Martijn Pieters could certainly answer this question. My opinion is that slice notation is often more efficient than function call. But in this peculiar case (slice with same indexes), `insert` might be good to. Why this question? Do you measure with `timeit`?

Answer (score 0):

**Implementation details**

According to the CPython implementation available on GitHub at https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c and https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c, we have:

The `insert()` method is defined in the following function:

```
static PyObject *
listinsert(PyListObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    Py_ssize_t i;
    PyObject *v;
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "nO:insert", &i, &v))
        return NULL;
    if (ins1(self, i, v) == 0)
        Py_RETURN_NONE;
    return NULL;
}
```

Which calls `ins1()` function, here is the C code:

```
static int
ins1(PyListObject *self, Py_ssize_t where, PyObject *v)
{
    Py_ssize_t i, n = Py_SIZE(self);
    PyObject **items;
    if (v == NULL) {
        PyErr_BadInternalCall();
        return -1;
    }
    if (n == PY_SSIZE_T_MAX) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_OverflowError,
            "cannot add more objects to list");
        return -1;
    }

    if (list_resize(self, n+1) < 0)
        return -1;

    if (where < 0) {
        where += n;
        if (where < 0)
            where = 0;
    }
    if (where > n)
        where = n;
    items = self->ob_item;
    for (i = n; --i >= where; )
        items[i+1] = items[i];
    Py_INCREF(v);
    items[where] = v;
    return 0;
}
```

The slice call is done by the `PyList_SetSlice()` function:

```
int
PyList_SetSlice(PyObject *a, Py_ssize_t ilow, Py_ssize_t ihigh, PyObject *v)
{
    if (!PyList_Check(a)) {
        PyErr_BadInternalCall();
        return -1;
    }
    return list_ass_slice((PyListObject *)a, ilow, ihigh, v);
}
```

The optimised implementation is done in:

```
static int
list_ass_slice(PyListObject *a, Py_ssize_t ilow, Py_ssize_t ihigh, PyObject *v)
```

The insertion is done in the following piece of code:

```
else if (d > 0) { /* Insert d items */
    k = Py_SIZE(a);
    if (list_resize(a, k+d) < 0)
        goto Error;
    item = a->ob_item;
    memmove(&item[ihigh+d], &item[ihigh],
        (k - ihigh)*sizeof(PyObject *));
}
for (k = 0; k < n; k++, ilow++) {
    PyObject *w = vitem[k];
    Py_XINCREF(w);
    item[ilow] = w;
}
```

Hope it helps!